# Are multi-threads really runs concurrently or inline (one after the other)

Tags: java, multithreading

I was sure the basic term of `MultiThreading` was clear to me - A process is consists of multiple threads and can run them concurrently, right?

I came across this [site](http://www.javatpoint.com/thread-scheduler-in-java), which declares:

> **Only one thread at a time can run in a single process.**
>
> The thread scheduler mainly uses preemptive or time slicing scheduling
>   to schedule the threads.

so what actually happens when writing:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    new CalcThread("CalcThread A").start();
    new CalcThread("CalcThread B").start();
}
```

Say the thread scheduler picked `thread a` to run first, and let's say `thread b` is going to be scheduled right after it. Is `thread b` going to run only after `thread a` has terminated?

If this is the case - why call it concurrency behaviour?

Comment: Don't believe in everything you read on the web. On a multi-core / multi-processor system multiple threads can of course run concurrently (that means: each doing work at the same time).

Comment: Please explain youself

Comment: Concurrent != parallel! A single core machine allows the *concurrent* running of multiple threads but not parallel execution. A multi-core machine allows parallel execution of multiple threads across multiple cores as well as concurrent execution of multiple threads on the individual cores.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, true. That's a subtle but important distinction. I should have been more careful when I wrote my comment (replace "concurrently" with "in parallel").

Comment: The statement, "only one thread at a time...", was true back in the 1990s when Java was new, and most computers had only one processor.  The state of the art changes.  Books don't.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `start()` *schedules* a thread to execute. While it usually executes "very soon after", actual execution commencement time is non-determinant; it's up to the JVM.

On multi-core machines, the other threads will (probably) execute concurrently on other cores while the main thread continues.

On single-core machines (eg a low spec AWS machine) the JVM may sequentially start-process-terminate each thread in turn before continuing to the main thread (I have seen this happen).

Comment: So, in multi-core machine - each thread could run on different core? meaning each thread has it own process?

Comment: @Nimrod, the wording is a bit off in what you found on the internet. A thread itself can be considered a light-weight process on a single- or multi-core machine. What having multiple cores would do is allow multiple threads to run in parallel not just concurrently.

Comment: @Nimrod, No.  A thread does not have processes.  A process has threads.  More specifically, a process is composed of a virtual address space, a set of other resources (e.g., open files), and a set of threads.  Each thread is an independent execution path through the code that is loaded into the process's address space.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily when the first running thread terminates (finishes doing all of its work) but rather when its time quantum expires or other factors like you gave as examples in your post.

With preemptive scheduling, a running thread may be stopped in favor of a higher priority thread or when a new thread enters that is expected to have the shortest time to complete based on historical data. There are many factors that may be considered with thread scheduling and the algorithms used to do it.

Yes, they're running concurrently in that they both can make progress at the same time but not in parallel (actually doing work at the same instance in time).